# Is there a more elegant solution to modify these file names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, os.path

I have an index at the "end" of the filename and want to be able to change it through a function. There are three different ways the files I'm taking in can be constructed that I included in the example arguments. This ended up making it confusing to deal with the different cases.

This is how I ended up doing it. It works but it is extremely confusing to look at. Is there a better way than this? Something more elegant but without sacrificing speed?

```
import os

def change_index(file, index):
    string_splits = os.path.basename(file).split("_")
    new_string_splits = '_'.join(string_splits[:3]), '_'.join(string_splits[3:])
    newer_string_splits = new_string_splits[1].split(".")
    newest_string_splits = '.'.join(newer_string_splits[:1]), '.'.join(newer_string_splits[1:])
    final_string = new_string_splits[0] + "_" + str(index) + "." + newest_string_splits[1]
    print("before path", file)
    print("after path ", os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), final_string))

change_index("/Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20201201_0.jpg", 3)
change_index("/Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20191111_0.example_photo.jpg", 12)
change_index("/Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20210604_0.example_photo.jpg.something.expl", 2)
```

Output:

```
before path /Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20201201_0.jpg
after path  /Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20201201_3.jpg
before path /Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20191111_0.example_photo.jpg
after path  /Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20191111_12.example_photo.jpg
before path /Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20210604_0.example_photo.jpg.something.expl
after path  /Users/Name/Documents/untitled folder 3/Photos_Friends_20210604_2.example_photo.jpg.something.expl
```

Comment: Can you give examples of input filenames and desired output filenames?

Comment: Will this "20201201" be in every image immediately preceding the number to be changed?

Comment: @IainShelvington If you run the code it provides that.

Comment: @LPR 20201201 is a date that can change depending on the file but it'll keep the same scheme. Sorry, I'll change those around to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is always a 8-digits date befor, you can use a regex for that

```
import re

def change_index(file, index):
    return re.sub(r"(\d{8})_\d", r"\1_" + str(index), file)
```

---

Be more specific

- If the number to replace is always a `zero`

  ```
  def change_index(file, index):
      return re.sub(r"(\d{8})_0", r"\1_" + str(index), file)
  ```
- A slightly more strict regex for the date part

  ```
  def change_index(file, index):
      return re.sub(r"([12][0-2]\d\d[0-1]\d[0-3]\d)_0", r"\1_" + str(index), file)
  ```

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks! It's not always a zero so I can't include that filter. Will look more into regex since it looks like another language to me right now, but if directories could potentially also be named after dates, this could cause an issue right? So probably safer to run it on the basename and add it back to the rest of the directory after?

Comment: @AskioFrio I let you try you'll see, but if the number is after a underscore just after dates : it'll work